# Stop wordpress from creating multiple size images

Tags: thumbnails, images

I want wordpress to stop making multiple size images cause it's going to eat up my storage space. So I went Settings > Media and then set all the sizes to 0. When I uploaded a new image it still is making 2 copies for example:

```
achannel.jpg
achannel-346x288.jpg
```

although they are both full size images so why does it need to create another full size image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'filter_image_sizes');
function filter_image_sizes( $sizes) {

    unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['large']);

    return $sizes;
}
```

Comment: it's 4 years ago but how can i only use add_filter if the upload comes from a specific plugin?

Comment: Preferably, you should use one of the filters from the plugin. If the plugin doesn't have one, then, depending on the plugin, maybe you might be able to use an if condition inside the function to check for the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

### Built in

Just set the sizes you don't need to `0`. This skips the process of creating them. I know, it's not documented, but it works.

[image]